# Update al hacer click en boton

Tags: php, sql

De nuevo, perdón la molestia, pero es que necesito terminar este trabajo, y esto ya sería lo ultimo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que, al hacer click en el botón actualizar se ejecute esta sentencia sql para que se actualice el total de la tabla:

> UPDATE factura1 SET total = (precioUnidad * cantidad);

hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

les dejo el código php por si quieren ver algo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias nuevamente.

pd: agrego foto del fichero consulta.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, siempre es bueno subir el código en texto que en imágenes, ya que si en algún momento el servidor donde se alojan las imágenes deja de funcionar la pregunta no estaría completa. Te invito a revisar [ask].

Comment: Si total es un campo calculado, lo mejor es que lo calcules en el `SELECT` cuando recuperas los datos y no lo almacenes en la base de datos. Ejemplo `SELECT *, (cantidad * precioUnidad) total FROM factura1;`

Comment: @Xerif eso hacia antes, pero lo modifique para que se guarde en la base de datos porque sin guardarlo no podía calcular el subtotal y todos los datos de abajo

Comment: @DavidBucci Si es un dato calculado, no es necesario para nada almecenarlo en la base de datos, lo mejor es calcularlo cuando lo necesites, ya sea el total o el subtotal. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una consulta ajax (Yo lo he hecho con JQuery que me resulta más fácil).

**Explicación:** PHP solo es de back-end y no de front-end por lo que no podrías ejecutar directamente desde PHP una llamada del front-end. (Explicación sencilla: Front-end=usuario, back-end=server). Por lo que por en medio existe ajax que puede ejecutar una consulta externa desde la misma página. Generas un fichero `.php` lo vamos a llamar `consulta.php` y el boton pongamos que tiene un `id` de `btnactualizar` (ya que no muestras el html).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btnactualizar").click(function(){
           var url="consulta.php"
           jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                success:function(output){
                    //Luego de ejecutar la llamada el output es lo que retornas
                    //con un echo normal
                }
            });
     });
});
```

Comment: solo para aclarar AJAX no depende de JQuery

Comment: gracias, no me queda claro bien como sería el fichero consulta.php..

ahi agrego una foto en el post, para que veas como se me ocurre hacerlo, pero seguro me falta algo, si me podrías ayudar con eso te agradezco.

Comment: Esta bien aunque yo le quitaría la creación de la base de datos ya que ya lo comprueba en el anterior fichero (te ahorras líneas de código). Luego si ocurre algún error no lo mostrará por lo que te recomiendo añadir un `if(!result){echo "Error";}else{}`

Comment: @matahombres la llamada de ajax no me esta funcionando, cuando hago click en actualizar no pasa nada.. ni siquiera me manda  a consulta.php

Comment: @matahombres perdon, ahi me funciono, pero tengo que apretar actualizar y luego refrescar la página, hay alguna forma que al apretar el botón actualizar se cambie automáticamente el contenido de "total" en la tabla?

Comment: Puedes hacer que la consulta ajax te retorne el total que se actualiza y a través de JQuery cambiar el campo por el nuevo contenido. Esto se puede lograr con un `.html()`